# I have three columns in google sheets, which are Gender, Name and Age. How can I return the value close to the average or median of the Age per Gender

Tags: google-sheets

```
Gender  Name    Age
Male    Rahul   5
Male    Vijay   3
Male    Amit    8
Male    Rohit   6
Male    Vinay   6
Male    Raj 4
Female  Sunita  3
Female  Siri    7
Female  Alexa   2
```

---

```
Gender  Avg Age Cloge to Average Age
Male    5.33    5
Female  4   3
```

---

```
Gender  Name    Age
Male    Rahul   5
Male    Vijay   3
Male    Amit    8
Male    Rohit   6
Male    Vinay   6
Male    Raj 4
Female  Sunita  3
Female  Siri    7
Female  Alexa   2
```

---

```
Gender  Avg Age Cloge to Average Age
Male    5.33    5
Female  4   3
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
={{"Gender","Average","Median"};byrow(unique(A2:A10),lambda(z,{z,round(average(filter(C:C,A:A=z)),2),median(filter(C:C,A:A=z))}))}
```

[image]